# Why is the normal vector different in cartesian coordinates vs. spherical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals, curvilinear-coordinates

Consider the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Let $\mathbf x(u,v)$ be a parameterization for the sphere.

Say I was trying to find specifically the normal vector given by $$ \frac{\partial \bf x}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \bf x}{\partial v} $$ (to for example, evaluate a surface integral)

> **Question.** Why is the value of this normal vector different when I evaluate it in cartesian coordinates vs spherical coordinates?

**1. Cartesian coordinates**
$$\mathbf{x}(u,v)= \langle u, v, \pm\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2} \rangle$$
First consider the positive case.

Then, the partial derivatives $$ \mathbf{x}_u(u,v)= (1,0,\frac {-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\mathstrut ) $$

$$\mathbf x_v(u,v)=(0,1,\frac {-y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\mathstrut )  $$

$$\mathbf{x}_u\times\mathbf{x}_v=\frac{1}{z}\langle x,y,z \rangle$$

**2. Spherical coordinates**

The sphere is given by $\rho = 1$ where $\phi \in [0,\pi]$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

Computing the cross product in spherical coordinates gives
$$\mathbf x_u   \times \mathbf x_v=\Biggl\vert \begin{array} 1\mathbf e_\rho   & \mathbf e_\phi   & \mathbf e_\theta    \\ 0 & h_\phi  & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & h_\theta  \end{array}\Biggr\vert = \rho^2\sin(\theta) \mathbf{e}_\rho = z\langle x,y,z \rangle $$

Where $\mathbf{e}_\rho$ etc are the unit basis vectors for spherical coordinates, and $h_\rho$ etc are their respective scale factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *unit* normal vector is the same. Different parametrizations of the same surface give different non-unit vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But if I was to calculate a surface integral, would both vectors give the same answer? Also, if the two vectors are different, then where did the vector $\mathbf{x}_u \times \mathbf{x}_v $ (in cartesian coordinates) get mapped to in sphericals? I guess I assumed that the mapping would preserve the same vector.

Comment: @user523384, yes. Different parametrizations are related by a change of variable.

Comment: But the vector obtained from a cross product in one coordinate system need not be mapped to the cross product of the same vectors in the new coordinate system? (Just want to make sure I haven't misunderstood something) i.e.
If $a\times b = c$  then $T(a\times b)=?= T(c)$?

Comment: @user523384, the direction is the same. The jacobian of the cov changes the lenght.

Comment: Hmm but the jacobian over here would be $\rho^2 \sin(\phi)$ I'm not sure why that explains a difference (since in cartesian it's not just (x,y,z) but 1/z (x,y,z))

Comment: @user523384, see "A proof of the independence of the surface integral with respect to parameterization": http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~dstewart/classes/22m042/stokes.pdf